# splitting custom function output in pandas to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried looking for similar answers, but solutions didn't work for me.

I have a dataframe with two columns:  template(str) and content(str).

I also have a separate function, `split_template_name` that takes a string and returns a tuple of 5 values, eg:

`split_template_name(some_string)` will return a tuple of 5 strings `('str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5')`

I'm trying to process the `df[template]` with this function, so that the dataframe gets 5 more columns with the 5 outputs.

Tried
`df[template].apply(split_template_name)` and it returns full tuple as one column, which is not what I need.

Some stackoverflow answers suggest adding `result_type='expand'`, So I tried `df['template'].apply(split_template_name, axis = 1, result_type ='expand')`
but that gives errors: `split_template_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'` or `split_template_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'`

Basically the goal is to start with `df['template', 'content']` and to end with dataframe that has `df['template', 'content', 'str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5']`

Comment: Can you provide the general logic of the split function, and a (dummy) sample of the data? Could it be vectorized?

Comment: the function is not really generic.  it just custom work on text that returns 5 relevant parameters in a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
df[['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5']] = pd.DataFrame(
    df['template'].apply(split_template_name).tolist(), index = df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's possible to split the column with a regular expression you could use:

```
df.template.str.extract()
```

see this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentences': ['how_are_you', 'hello_world_good']})
```

how this dataframe looks like:

```
          sentences
0       how_are_you
1  hello_world_good
```

using Series.str.extract()

```
df['sentences'].str.extract(r'(?P<first>\w+)_(?P<second>\w+)_(?P<third>\w+)')
```

output:

```
   first second third
0    how    are   you
1  hello  world  good
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this does not apply to my case

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
df_dict = {"template" :["A B C D E","A B C D E","A B C D E","A B C D E","A 
    B C D E"], "content" : ["text1","text2","text3","text4","text5"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

print(df)

    template    content
0   A B C D E   text1
1   A B C D E   text2
2   A B C D E   text3
3   A B C D E   text4
4   A B C D E   text5


def split_template_name(row):
    return row.split()
df[['A','B','C','D','E']] = df['template'].apply(split_template_name)

print(df)


template    content A   B   C   D   E
0   A B C D E   text1   A   A   A   A   A
1   A B C D E   text2   B   B   B   B   B
2   A B C D E   text3   C   C   C   C   C
3   A B C D E   text4   D   D   D   D   D
4   A B C D E   text5   E   E   E   E   E
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).